# How to use same function for Dev and Production - Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase and cloud functions, please try to help.

I have an app that uses cloud function to call external APIs. As my app is now live and consuming those APIs through cloud functions. I have to develop new features in my app using Dev environment without disturbing Live functions.

There are two different URLs of external APIs for Dev and Production.

For example:

```
Dev = demoapi.example.com/someapi

Live = api.example.com/someapi
```

How can i only upload cloud functions to dev environment without disturbing LIVE app.

Do i have to write copy of each function in my index file? Or is there any other way? becuase there are around 20 functions.

Both Dev and Production DBs/Projects are different in firebase. But i can only pay for one blaze plan (as cloud function requires blaze plan to make external requests) so i want to use one project for functions.

Making copy of each function is not the right choice.